# How to determine whether a mini PCI-Express supports the USB Interface?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, pci-express, minipci

I'm eyeing the amazing [Option GTM671W](http://www.roundsolutions.com/techdocs/ds/GTM671W.pdf), which is a half-height mPCIe card that supports both WLAN and 3G. However, it was designed for the mPCIe v 1.2 specification. According to [this discussion](http://www.micropctalk.com/forums/showpost.php?p=63065&postcount=7), its 3G capability requires the mPCIe USB interface.

Using HWiNFO64, I determined that my Dell Inspiron 1545's motherboard (DELL 0G848F) supports PCIe v1.1, and I'm not sure if it supports the mPCIe USB interface. This wireless card is on the expensive side and hard to get, so I'm loathe to take the try-it-and-see approach.

Is there any way to determine whether a given mPCIe slot supports the mPCIe USB interface?

I found the electromechanical specification documents for mPCIe versions 1.1 and 1.2. It seems that they incorporated the USB interface in v 1.1, but I'm still not sure, and I'm hoping someone with more experience could clarify.

Unfortunately, I cannot link to the documents directly due to insufficient reputation. I will update this question with the relevant links when my reputation rises. Please search for the following online:

- PCI Express™ Mini Card Electromechanical Specification Revision 1.1RD
- PCI Express® Mini Card Electromechanical Specification Revision 1.2

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Given that mPCI-Express standard itself is backwards compatible due to PCI-Express being backwards compatible I would place the chances of it working at around 99.99%.  I would still contact Dell to determine if it supports the mPCIe USB interface

Answer (score 2):

Most laptop miniPCIe slots do NOT support USB, but it is very difficult to tell the difference.

The mini PCIe form factor only defines the physical dimensions of the card and slot, not the electrical specifications, therefore the slot can (and is) used for both USB, PCIe, and SATA connectivity and not all slots implement all electrical standards.

This is a source of much confusion which was why the NGFF (m.2) standard explicitly addressed this by adding keying tabs to indicate which slots and cards had USB/SATA/PCIe.

In your particular case the chances are 100% that **it will not work unless your laptop already has a SIM card slot**. Dell boards often have multiple Mini PCIe slots, but you will need one marked "WWAN" to have any chance of it working. As far as I'm aware, some Inspirons had this option but most do not.

Remember that in addition to the USB interface, the board must also have a SIM card slot and a way for the 3G card to communicate with it. This is hard-wired into the MiniPCIe slot, so a laptop must be designed with WWAN (3G) in mind from the outset.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I think I figured out how to get the device name of the PCI controller, which can be used to look up its specs. I'll post the details in a separate answer as soon as I'm sure that I'm reading the docs correctly. In my case, I'm now pretty confident that the mPCIe slot supports USB. However, you're quite right re: the SIM issue. If the GTM671W requires the User Identity Module (UIM) interface, then I might be out of luck, since the specs for my controller (Intel 82801IB ICH9) mention nothing about SIM or UIM.

Comment: At the risk of veering off-topic, if the mobo does not include a SIM slot, it is possible to obtain a SIM card adapter which wraps around the smaller half of the mPCIe card (Pins 1-16) before it is inserted into the slot. One such adapter (KZ-B15) is manufactured by the Taiwanese company Bplus Tech. Co. and their PDF for the product illustrates this installation process:  http://www.hwtools.net/PDF/B15_brief.pdf

Comment: @IllyaMoskvin: Good find. I'm aware of slot-sized adapters that often make the device too big to fit in a laptop, but didn't know about the ones that wrap into the slot itself.