# How to connect mini PCIe that uses USB to PCIe?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, pci-express, minipci, m2-connector

I have a [Quectel LTE-A EM160R-GL](https://www.quectel.com/product/lte-a-em160r-gl) which I need to connect to a motherboard, this module is using `M.2 using the USB interface`.

I have read similar posts such as these:
[Does a mini PCIe to PCIe slot adapter exist?](https://superuser.com/questions/1329024/does-a-mini-pcie-to-pcie-slot-adapter-exist)
[How to determine whether a mini PCI-Express supports the USB Interface?](https://superuser.com/questions/990765/how-to-determine-whether-a-mini-pci-express-supports-the-usb-interface)

I understand that most adapters only support `PCIe interface`, and not `USB`, and it seems to me like the ones who do support `USB`, require a 9 or 19 pin USB cable to be plugged into the motherboard USB header, my problem is that I don't have any USB headers on my motherboard and only a single PCIe slot.

Is there a way for me to connect my module to my motherboard using the PCIe slot?

Comment: My PCIE wi-fi card is a M.2 with USB to PCIE adapter, plus a M.2 wifi card.